# IE8 & 9 - no jquery ajax response object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

jquery version: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

```
    $.ajax({
        url: CI_ROOT + current_page + '/get_results' ,
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'primary_key': primary_key, 'search_category':search_category, 'sub_category': sub_category ,'search_page':search_page, 'search_order': search_order, 'project_type': project_type},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.browse-list').html(spinner);
            $('.page-number-nav').html('');
        },          
        success: function(r){
            var response_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(r.responseText);

            $('.browse-list').html('');

            if (response_obj.status == 'SUCCESS')
            {               
                $('#sort_menu').hide();
                $('#sort_type').hide();

                if ((response_obj.results != 'No results') && (search_category != 'group') && (search_category == 'title' || (primary_key > 0)))
                {
                    $('#sort_menu').show(); 
                    $('#sort_type').show();             
                }

                $('.browse-list').html(response_obj.results);
                $('.page-number-nav').html(response_obj.pagination);
            }
        }
    });
```

if (r.responseText == undefined){alert('Empty');} returns Empty for IE 8 & 9, but works for IE10 & all other browsers

I've read & tried every post here I can find that might be relevant, cannot understand why this only bombs for those two browsers, and what to check for

TIA!

Comment: What content type are you sending back from the server?

Comment: json, via:  echo json_encode($retval); return;

valid for everyone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving you ajax call a `dataType` like so:

```
dataType: 'json'
```

so it knows what kind of data you are expecting.
You should also return the `content type` in the response header from the server as `application/json` - your `json_encode` method just converts your object to JSON, but apparently does not apply the correct headers (ref [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#95667))

You'll want to add:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
```

With the `dataType` declared explicitly there shouldn't be any need for the `jQuery.ParseJSON`, as it will convert it before it calls the `success` handler, so the parameter `r` will be the JSON you are expecting :)

Also just a note (as OP found out) that the `header` function call needs to be before your `json_encode` call

Comment: I've tried variations on those, but will give it one more shot to let you know

Comment: does the parameter `r` contain any information? is it just the responseText not coming through?

Comment: making your changes, and adding: alert(Object.keys(r)); I see it has the normal response object properties, but not the responseText or anything else I'm sending back

Comment: (removing your changes is the same, so they don't appear to have done anything. )

Comment: How are you testing IE8 out of curiousity? (Are you using IE10 with compatibility on or IETester or straight out older browser?)

Comment: IE compatibility, in the debugger - don't know testing IE very well :-(

Comment: If you're pressing `F12` in IE and changing the browser mode in the toolbar - make sure the Document Mode is set to `standards` and not `querks` mode, I've heard `querks` does some funky things with JS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38079/discussion-between-jmadsen-and-m-t-bennett)

Comment: It looks like your header() suggestion was the ticket - just had to put it in the right place in my code. thanks!

Comment: Where in code did you have to place it? at the top? Ill update my answer to reflect it

Comment: it was common sense once I stopped & thought: header() went in my backend function, right before the json_encode() line, so the return was properly encoded